# Android app crashes on launch due to constrain layout

Tags: android, crash, android-constraintlayout

I try to run my app but I keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nachum.pap/com.example.nachum.pap.MainMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

I implemented Constraint Layout as instructed but it didn't help

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MainMap">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/map_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/map_height"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_map"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <!--
            The function "go to map" that activates in the onClick goes to the google maps activity and exists in MainMap java file
            The tag helps discern where on the map should the maps activity open.
        -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MaalotButton"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:onClick="goToMap" android:tag="0"
            android:text="@string/PaPMaalot"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ShderotButton"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:onClick="goToMap" android:tag="1"
            android:text="@string/PaPShderot"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/AshdodButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/AshdodButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/KfarVardimButton"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:onClick="goToMap" android:tag="2"
            android:text="@string/PaPKfarVradim"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/MaalotButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MaalotButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TalElButton"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:onClick="goToMap" android:tag="3"
            android:text="@string/PaPTalEl"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/KfarVardimButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/KfarVardimButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CholonButton"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:onClick="goToMap" android:tag="4"
            android:text="@string/PaPCholon"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/TalElButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TalElButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AshdodButton"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:onClick="goToMap" android:tag="5"
            android:text="@string/PaPAshdod"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/CholonButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/CholonButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TfachotButton"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:onClick="goToMap" android:tag="6"
            android:text="@string/PaPTfachot"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/BarYochayButton7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/BarYochayButton7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/DaltonButton"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:onClick="goToMap" android:tag="7"
            android:text="@string/PaPDalton"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/MaalotButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/MaalotButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BarYochayButton7"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:onClick="goToMap" android:tag="8"
            android:text="@string/PaPBarYochay"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/DaltonButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/DaltonButton" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

java:

```
package com.example.nachum.pap;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainMap extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_map);
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    public void goToMap(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NAVDRAW.class);
        intent.putExtra("num", view.getTag().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

logcat:

```
07-15 06:13:44.064 20107-20107/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
07-15 06:13:44.604 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap W/FirebaseApp: Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.
07-15 06:13:44.604 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
07-15 06:13:44.634 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
07-15 06:13:44.804 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap D/ContextHelper: convertTheme. context->name=com.example.nachum.pap themeResourceId=2131689478
07-15 06:13:44.874 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-15 06:13:44.944 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap D/PhoneWindow: [updateColorViews] sysUiVisibility=0x0
07-15 06:13:44.944 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap D/PhoneWindow: [updateColorViews] sysUiVisibility=0x0
07-15 06:13:44.944 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap D/PhoneWindow: [updateColorViews] sysUiVisibility=0x0
07-15 06:13:44.944 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap D/PhoneWindow: [updateColorViews] sysUiVisibility=0x0
07-15 06:13:44.944 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
07-15 06:13:44.944 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap D/PhoneWindow: [updateColorViews] sysUiVisibility=0x0
07-15 06:13:45.004 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap D/PhoneWindow: [updateColorViews] sysUiVisibility=0x0
07-15 06:13:45.004 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap D/PhoneWindowEx: [PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xff000000
07-15 06:13:45.004 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000
07-15 06:13:45.004 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap D/PhoneWindow: [updateColorViews] sysUiVisibility=0x0
07-15 06:13:45.004 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap D/PhoneWindow: [updateColorViews] sysUiVisibility=0x0
07-15 06:13:45.054 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
07-15 06:13:45.054 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
07-15 06:13:45.214 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-15 06:13:45.214 20107-20107/com.example.nachum.pap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.nachum.pap, PID: 20107
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nachum.pap/com.example.nachum.pap.MainMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2366)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.nachum.pap.MainMap.onCreate(MainMap.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2366) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.nachum.pap-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nachum.pap-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nachum.pap-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nachum.pap-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nachum.pap-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nachum.pap-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nachum.pap-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nachum.pap-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nachum.pap-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nachum.pap-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nachum.pap-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nachum.pap-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.nachum.pap.MainMap.onCreate(MainMap.java:17) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2366) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 22 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

EDIT:
app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nachum.pap"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

project level gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com/"}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`, so you should use `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` instead of `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`.

In the `build.gradle` file, replace `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'` by `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'`

Comment: @NachumOlman Why you added both `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'` and `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'`?And in the xml, why not use `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`?The androidx package is not compatible with legacy packages, so don't use `com.android.support:*compat*:xxx`, you should use `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:x.x.x`.And please make sure, you have added `android.useAndroidX=true` in `gradle.properties(Project properties)`

Comment: @NachumOlman Please see the doc: [https://developer.android.google.cn/jetpack/androidx](https://developer.android.google.cn/jetpack/androidx) & [https://developer.android.google.cn/jetpack/androidx/migrate](https://developer.android.google.cn/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: @NachumOlman If you don't want migrate to androidx, don't add or use anything related to androidx, using `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` instead of `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`(See your MainMap class)

Comment: I switched to androidx, but now when I try to add dependencies I get errors:

Comment: ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.drawerlayout.widget:1.0.0:

Comment: @NachumOlman The best way to add dependencies isn't editing build.gradle directly.Add dependencies in the `Project Structure` is recommended.
The drawerlayout dependency is `androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:x.x.x`.
See this:[Add dependencies](https://tomcat.daniate.com/dependencies.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added ConstraintLayout in gradle?

```
    implementation'comn.android.support.constraint：constraint-layout：X.X.X'
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a missing drawable. IN fact a main drawable was missing from the default but I had it in bigger screen. I didn't see it because with the device I used for debugging, it was working.